# I am implementing a server-client based TictacToe . But I am getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, client-server

**In server.py [server.py][1]**    / I am getting the following error , when clicking on the squares of the game for the move .

```
File "server.py", line 36, in run
        self.connection.send((self.mark) )
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Server.py:** [1]: http://pastebin.com/HR3DC6Kd

In client.py [client.py][1] I am getting the following error:

```
File "client.py", line 132, in sendClickedSquare
    if self.myTurn:
AttributeError: 'TicTacToeClient' object has no attribute 'myTurn'
```

**client.py** [1]: http://pastebin.com/dexntYKx

I am using python3  . How to solve this ? I have tried everything .

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i think that the server error is because of the fact that you are passing string  instead of unicode. As for the client, I see that the myTurn attribute is not present in the __init__ method. Was that intentional ?

Comment: @SuburbanFilth . These codes that I am using is being taken from the book , How to Program Python  by deitel . So I have no Idea was it intentional or not  ?

Comment: @SuburbanFilth  and for the string error , how to fix that  ?

Comment: if it code from book than it can be for Python2 which treats socket data as `string` but Python3 treats as `bytes`. You have to `encode()` string to bytes before you send it, and `decode()` bytes to string when you receive data.

Comment: @furas . yes I fixed that thing , but I am still can't make it work for either of python3 and python2

Comment: please don't post links to code on another site. Reduce the problem down to the smallest amount of code and post it in your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is for Python2 in which there is no difference between `string` and `bytes` but Python3 needs to `encode()` from `string` to `bytes` and `decode()` from `bytes` to `string`

Because you don't use native characters then you can decode/encode using `ascii` instead of `utf-8` or other

```
value = self.connection.recv(1).decode('ascii')

self.connection.send(value.encode('ascii'))
```

- server: http://pastebin.com/AukYz3WM
- client: http://pastebin.com/1hcHWPic

---

BTW: After that you will no problem with `myTurn` because above problem generated exception and program couldn't set `self.myTurn = 0`

Comment: But still after the player 1 has made a move the player 2 can't make the move . Would you please see it  ?

Comment: always run code in console - and you will see error message - I missed one `recv()`. Now all `recv()`/`send()` have `decode()`/`encode()`. Other problem can be that server ends work after first move - but it is different problem so use debuger or at least `print()` to find problem before you create new question on SO. Even book's authors make mistakes in code.

Comment: I found problem - but there is no easy solution. Client uses `recv(34)` to receive messages but server sends different length messages and client receives two messages as one: `Opponent moved.9`. First message is `Opponent moved.` and second is oponent move `9`. Now second `recv()` wait for `9` but there is no second message. If you use shorter `recv(15)` to get only `Opponent moved.` you may have problem with other messages.

Comment: Solution: send message length as two char (and receive with `recv(2)`) and then use it with `recv(length)` to receive message. Instead of two chars you could send `int` converted to 4 bytes using `struck.pack()` and unconverted using `strict.unpack()`

Comment: I changed code (in the same links) and now message sends its length - ie. `15Opponent moved.`. This can be called "protocol" - like "HTTP", or "FTP".